# Instantiate plugins efficiently with observer pattern (php)

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I'm implementing the observer pattern to all plugins to interact with my web app. Now, I want to make installing plugins painless (i.e just putting files into a plugin folder) like most web apps do.

For example:
A plugin with the name "Awesome Stuff" that executes code based on events that occur in the Auth class and the Content class would include the following files in the "/plugin" directory.
AwesomeStuffAuth.php
AwesomeStuffContent.php

I've got a solution that's working, but I'm afraid it's not efficient, as it has to cycle through ALL the declared classes before it actually finds what it's looking for.

```
    function __construct() {

   //Get files in plugin directory that work on Auth
   foreach (glob("plugins/*AuthPlugin.php") as $filename) {

    //Include'em
    include_once($filename);


   }
   //Get all declared classes
   foreach (get_declared_classes() as $class){
        if (substr($class,-10)=='AuthPlugin'){
            $obj = new $class;
            $this->addObserver($obj);
        }

   }
```

}

This is the __construct() method that I use with the Auth class, and other classes would have similar methods.

Is this an efficient way of doing this? **Is it worth me connecting to a database to avoid cycling through all the declared classes?** How about flat file?

Thanks so much for taking a look at this.

Comment: Why include `Auth` in `Awesome Stuff`'s filename?

Comment: What will the plugins do to manipulate the auth object? I'm trying to understand why you dont create an AwesomeStuffAuth class that extends the original Auth class. Can you describe a situation where that doesn't work? Your example is very minimal and I can't see how you're going to interact with the plugins.

Comment: @JaredFarrish , thats so the application knows that plugin is manipulating the auto class

Comment: @stereofrog that's good news, how about those includes and searching the filesystem with glob

Comment: @Dan I'm implementing the observer pattern, which means i "addObservers" and then notify them when certain events happen (like a successful or unsuccessful login), at which point an observer object will or will not execute some code. I know that's not too clear, but a quick google would ilucidate it all.

Comment: I know what the observable pattern is. However, you write 'that manipulates the Auth class' so I was wondering if you were looking for something along inheritance. What you are describing in your comment does not manipulate the class but perform tasks depending on an emitted event. For the task you're trying to perform I think your   code should perform well enough.

Comment: @Dan sorry about the confusion, I'm new to the lingo :D

Comment: I think you should store them in the database, but you should cache in a session var. If the session var is empty, then rebuild it from the database. Also create a settings table entry as a signal so that it tells all sessions to rebuild from the database -- like when a new plugin is added, it trips this signal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution would be to use __autoload to catch the moment where the plugin is requested and add it to a list of observers at this moment, based on naming conventions:

```
function __autoload($class) {
     include_once 'plugins/' . $class . '.php';
     $observable = substr($class,-16);  # E.g. 'Auth'
     $observable::addObserverClass($class); 
}
```

then in the Auth class:

```
class Observable {

   static $observer_classes = array();

   static function addObserverClass($class) {
      self::$observer_classes[] = $class;
   }

   static function addObservers($self) {
      foreach(self::$observer_classes as $class) {
         $self->addObserver($class);
      }
   }

   function addObserver($class) {
      # Add the Observer.
   }
}

class Auth extends Observable {
   function __construct() {
      self::addObservers($self);
   }
}
```

Haven't tested the code, but you should get the idea. It eliminates both the need to glob and the need to iterate over every declared class each time a class is created.